# How can I get all Elements by Class type in my vba webbrowser document?

Tags: vba, excel, webbrowser-control

The code below is in an Excel 2010 form with a webbrowser control on it.

The Microsoft HTML Object Library is selected in the VBE references section and I'm using VBA 7.0.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.google.com/"
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

    Dim Inputs As IHTMLElementCollection

    'returns inputs on page where class name is "gsfi"
    Set Inputs = wb.Document.GetElementsByClassName("gsfi")
    'returns all inputs on a page
    Set Inputs = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")

    Debug.Print Inputs.Length

End Sub
```

**Edit:** I am amending this question in light of help from @Tim Williams to illustrate what I'm actually after. How can I get the all elements with the TagName "Input" and Class Type of "Text" or "Button" etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there are elements with that class name ?
Code below indicates there are no inputs with that class...

EDIT: "Type" is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

    Dim Inputs As IHTMLElementCollection, o As Object

    Set Inputs = pDisp.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Debug.Print Inputs.Length '>>11

    For Each o In Inputs
        Debug.Print o.Name, o.tagName, o.Type 
    Next o

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, rookie mistake! I was trying to find out if a class type could be found not the actual name. Is there a way to do this? I will edit the Question appropriately.